# Que/qui et l'imparfait

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, pronoms-relatifs

Est-ce qu'on peut utiliser l'imparfait après *qui* ou *que* ?

Dans une rédaction, j'ai écrit la phrase suivante mais je ne suis pas sure qu'elle soit correcte :

> Rendre le transport collectif gratuit est très bénéfique surtout pour les étudiants qui prenaient le transport quotidiennement

J'ai utilisé l'imparfait car l'action de prise de transport est répétitive et parce que dans les romans c'est souvent utilisé alors que d'après les règles générales, on n'utilise que le subjonctif ou bien le présent.

Comment: Je ne sais pas de quelle règle générale tu parles, mais il n'y a pas de problème à utiliser l'imparfait après *qui* ou *que* : "*Il rendait régulièrement visite aux personnes qui comptaient pour lui*".

Comment: Dans ta phrase il y a surtout un problème de concordance des temps. Pourquoi utiliser le présent puis le passé ? Ça peut être justifié dans le passé décrit une action terminée ("*Les gens qui mangeaient beaucoup de bonbons quand ils étaient enfant ont plus de problèmes de dentition à l'âge adulte.*") mais pas dans ta phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les pronoms relatifs « qui » et « que » ou la conjonction « que » ne déterminent pas le temps à utiliser.

1/ L'action d'utiliser un moyen de transport n'est pas appelée « répétitive » mais « habituelle ».
2/ En français on ne dit pas « prendre un transport » mais « utiliser un moyen de transport ». S'il s'agit de transport public on peut dire « prendre un transport en commun » ([très courant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transport+en+commun%2Ctransport+collectif&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctransport%20en%20commun%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctransport%20collectif%3B%2Cc0));  « transport collectif » est un terme qui englobe le transport en commun et que l'on confond parfois avec celui-ci ; on ne dit pas « prendre un transport collectif » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prennennt+les+transports+collectifs%2Cprennent+les+transports+en+commun&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprennent%20les%20transports%20en%20commun%3B%2Cc0)). Dans le cas de la question il s'agit de transport en commun et de transport public (très probablement). Voir [l'encyclopédie en ligne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_en_commun) pour des détails intéressants à ce sujet. 
3/ Dans le cas d'un avantage matériel basique, comme dans ce cas un avantage monétaire, « bénéfique » ne convient pas bien ; un adjectif comme « avantageux » est beaucoup mieux.
4/ L'action de rendre le transport collectif gratuit n'est pas avantageuse pour qui que ce soit, ce qui peut être  avantageux c'est le résultat, c'est à dire le transport collectif gratuit.

Si cette action se situe dans le passé on doit parler de ce qui s'y rapporte au passé si cela a une incidence dans le passé, même si cela reste vrai au moment ou on parle ; comme l'imparfait est bien utilisé pour une action habituelle dans le passé la phrase donne ceci ;

- Le transport collectif gratuit était très avantageux, surtout pour les étudiants qui utilisaient un moyen de transport quotidiennement.

*Les conditions matérielles sont directement connectées à la caractéristique d'être avantageux et l'avantage était évidemment une réalité dans le passé, donc on utilise l'imparfait.*

Évidemment il y a un autre contexte, celui dans lequel l'action habituelle a une conséquence dans le présent et alors on utilise le présent.

- Avoir réduit les activités sportives a pour conséquence de meilleurs résultats scolaires  chez les étudiants qui pratiquaient celle de leur choix régulièrement.

On n'utilise pas le présent pour des actions habituelles dans le passé ; on l'utilise seulement pour des actions habituelles dans un passé plus ou moins récent et qui se prolongent dans le futur ou tout au moins dont on pense qu'elles doivent se prolonger ;

- Il part pour l'école régulièrement tous les matins à six heures quinze.

Si on utilise le subjonctif c'est que l'action n'est pas réalisée ; cependant on l'utilise pour exprimer une action habituelle dans le futur, dans le présent et dans le passé ;

- Il fallait qu'il aille prendre le train tous les matin et il a préféré acheter une voiture.
- Il est nécessaire qu'il fasse un peu d'exercice tous les matins, sa santé en dépend.
- Il faudra qu'il se présente à la gendarmerie tous les jours, c'est la condition de sa mise en liberté provisoire.

Comment: pour que  je vous mettez  dans le contexte le sujet de la rédaction est le suivant : faudrait il rendre le transprot collectif gratuit pour les étudiants en argumentant

Comment: lorqu'on doute l'utilisation du temps correct présent ou imparfait lequel des deux est acceptable

Comment: @user19324 Désolé, j'ai du mal à saisir ce que vous essayez d'expliquer ; vous avez un devoir de rédaction ; sujet : rendre les transports en commun gratuit pour les étudiants ; façon de traiter le sujet : je ne comprends pas cette partie. Si la phrase dans votre question est une phrase personnelle dans votre rédaction alors il faut un **présent** (présent d'habitude, il a la même forme que le présent normal mais on déduit du contexte qu'il marque une action qui est répétée plus ou moins régulièrement). vous devez aussi avoir un présent dans la principale, comme expliqué : (champ 1)

Comment: @user19324 « Le transport collectif gratuit **est** très avantageux, surtout pour les étudiants qui **utilisent** un moyen de transport quotidiennement. ». Cela se comprend puisque parler d'une gratuité qui n'existe pas encore est fait dans l'intention de personne qui vont en profiter, donc l'action doit être prolongée dans le futur (donc présent habituel). (fin)

Comment: ok merci ,  dernière question :  est ce que c'est mieux d'utiliser dans les productions écrites le présent que l'imparfait surtout lorsqu'il s'agit d'argumentation pour les verbes précédés d'un pronoms relatifs ???

Comment: @user19324 Idon't have  the least idea what your problem might be ; as it appears it'll take a long discussion to make this clearer; another mode of exchange is necessary ; that is, we must open a chat room ; if you want to go on that way tell me and I'll open it ; we'll then be able to talk out the problem.

Comment: ok it sound good